# Does the Power Balance energy bracelet make you healthier?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do those hologram bracelets do anything at all?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/716/do-those-hologram-bracelets-do-anything-at-all)

Nowadays, many shops sell energy bracelet which claims to improve your health because the bracelet have some kind of force field around your hand. This claim is rather non-sense to me and a [guy](http://skepticblog.org/2010/09/23/power-balance-magical-energy-bracelets-or-nonsense/) also disagree with this.

Do you scientist make some test to these claims?

Comment: "Do you scientists ..."? I didn't realize being a skeptic made you a scientist. That's awesome!