# Are permanent magnets harmful to people?

Tags: magnetism

Some people who claimed to know things about human physiology and biology once told me that when held in a hand, a permanent magnet affects blood cells (specifically *ferrum* in them) and makes your grip temporarily stronger (until the blood flow adjusts to the effect) at the cost of some harm done to muscle tissue due to unusual conditions. Is any of that true?

Comment: Do you have a reference to your claim?

Comment: No, they were visitors on a science event at my school quite some time ago and I've been wondering about that ever since.

Comment: We live on a giant permanent magnet called Earth.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/136/243).

Comment: Lacks any references.